# Typescript factory pattern with parameters

Tags: typescript

I am currently using factory pattern in my project, below is the minimal reproducible code

```js
class A {
    constructor(public name: string) {}
}

class B {
    constructor(public age: number, public address: string) {}
}

type FactoryMap = {
    A: A,
    B: B
}

const map = {
    A,
    B
}

function create<T extends keyof FactoryMap>(name: T, ...params: ConstructorParameters<typeof FactoryMap[T]>): FactoryMap[T] {
    switch (name) {
        case "A":
            return new A(...params);
        case "B":
            return new B(...params);
    }
}

function create2<T extends keyof typeof map>(name: T, ...params: ConstructorParameters<typeof map[T]>): typeof map[T] {
    return new map[name](...params);
}
```

I've tried two different functions, but neither could work.

The first one said `Type 'A' is not assignable to type 'A & B'`, but I wonder `FactoryMap[T]` should be `A | B`.

The second one's error is `Type 'A | B' is not assignable to type '{ A: typeof A; B: typeof B; }[T]'`, I know why but I can't infer `A | B` using the object `map`.

Does anyone has solutions on those two functions?

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQ1XWAewHYQC4CcBXYXDfACgAdCAjEAS2GizAFsBTALmj33qwDmASkQBfJOKShIMAEKIUaTDgLFSFanUbQwArs0Ksa7fABpomhkzAATG-nZRuvfsLESkSXAE9K7aABiYCRk3gCyYJTQALwKaHDcsKaKqLLcsh4AZoRYJPTY6A5guOwAPAAq0OwAHiVYNjAA1uzeGJmBwerhkQB85Cwc3OXmAHRjlGD4bBDcAMLYvGpkAAqTbOwl%20BClPn5tHSH43ZQA2uUAuj1C3EGHx2fncWgQAO70uMAAFtD96yLI8XiwEg-gARLBQZwUoD4g5cIR8FhmOwXnByGMRhMpqwIEIANzQoEg6Cg2SQwkw6BwhFIrAo6CydHjNY4-HQ8SSZR4aCsSIxJ6oJLQjLibK5XD5JHAIolABMFSqtXY9SaLX2u3Y%2015lD6A30w2gGKx0zmC1Uh1W2I2Jm2Gq1kQeV24dva2oeAqpGxpyNRbr15yZmJZuIJoiAA)

Comment: as types exist only through a compilation phase what is the reason in `create` function? instead of calling create<A> just create an object with `new A(...)` command.

Comment: @AndrejKirejeŭ Similar to `document.createElement("div" | "span" | "p")`, I can easily create instances of different types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript will not be able to evaluate conditional types that contain unresolved type parameters. You could solve this with overloads:

```
class A {
    private name!: string
    constructor() {}
}

class B {
    private age!: number
    constructor() {}
}

const map = { A, B }

function create2<T extends keyof typeof map>(name: T, ...params: ConstructorParameters<typeof map[T]>): InstanceType<typeof map[T]>
function create2(name: keyof typeof map, ...params: ConstructorParameters<typeof map[keyof typeof map]>): InstanceType<typeof map[keyof typeof map]> {
    return new map[name](...params);
}
```

I added `InstanceType` on the return type. `typeof map[keyof typeof map]` will be the union `typeof A | typeof B` (ie either of the classes). Since we return an instance, we need to use `InstanceType` to get that.

The version above will not actually work if you have parameters to the constructor. This is because Typescript won't be able to follow that `params` and `map[name]` are in any way correlated. So TS sees `new (A | B)(...(parmsForA | paramsForB)` which is only sometimes safe (if `A` is paired with `paramsForB` this would be an error)

Now since we know that the two are actually correlated, this is a good use of a type assertion:

```
class A {
    constructor(public name: string) {}
}

class B {
    constructor(public age: number, public address: string) {}
}

const map = { A, B }

function create2<T extends keyof typeof map>(name: T, ...params: ConstructorParameters<typeof map[T]>): InstanceType<typeof map[T]>
function create2(name: keyof typeof map, ...params: any[]): InstanceType<typeof map[keyof typeof map]> {
    return new (map[name] as any)(...params)
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=14&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQ1XWAewHYQC4CcBXYXDfACgAdCAjEAS2GizAFsBTALmj33qwDmASkQBfJOKShIMAEKIUaTDgLFSFanUbQwArs0Ksa7fABpomhkzAATG-nZRuvfsLESkU7HmiswlaABeRDhzeUkAM0IsEnpsdAcwXHYAJgAeABVodgAPZKwbGABrdgBPDAjoXFLKdgrffwA+chYObgzzADpuyjB8NghuAGFvVRIyAAU+tnZk-Ag06tr6v0oAbQyAXUahbgBJFTAY9gya9kWzlf8N7aQomNw4rAT2JNSWme4S8sqlusrVl0etNWIMdFhSmtNrtoAc8EdgCczhdlgDrt96n8rpRtgo0NAHLhCPhnlh2AB3aDkVZrVrsTY6GBHUpCcjdTq9fqgoQSIA)

Comment: Nice work! But I can't figure out the meaning of using overload, without overload, I can achieve the same effect. [playground](https://tsplay.dev/WJR75W)

Comment: @crazyones110 The overload is there for good client side types. `create2("A", ...paramsOfA)` shold return an instance of `A`. If the implementation signature were the only one , that would return `A | B`

Comment: why do you cast `map[name] as any`? Don't you break the type checking here?

Comment: @GuerricP My point is that in this case there isn't a version of this that will type check currently

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir In my playground, the implementation signature is the only one, TS still can correctly infer type `"A"` or `"B"` for template parameter `T` and the return type is `A` or `B` corresponding to inferred `T`

Comment: @GuerricP I think TS has no way to know that `params` and `map[name]` are in any way corelated, but we know for sure, so we can use type assertion here. I like that `Now since we know that the two are actually correlated, this is a good use of a type assertion`

Comment: Usually I `curry` map data structure. [Example](https://tsplay.dev/mMVklW) . However it has its own drawback. `new (map[name])(...params)` inside the function infered as `any`