# Higher order function, how to deduct injected type from model without casting

Tags: typescript

I am a bit stuck with the pretty simple idea:

Imagine that we have simple high order function that accepts another function and some object and returns another function:

```js
const hof = (callback, data)=> (model) => callback({...data, ...model});
```

Now I want to make it:

- type-safe
- type-smart - exclude from `model` properties that already present id `data`

From the first sight it might looks like this:

```js
const hof = <TModel extends object, TInject extends Partial<TModel>, TRes>(callback: (m: TModel) => TRes, inject: TInject) =>
    (m: Omit<TModel, keyof TInject> ) =>
        callback({ ...inject, ...m})
```

However, it produces an error:

> Argument of type 'TInject & Omit<TModel, keyof TInject>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TModel'. 'TInject & Omit<TModel, keyof TInject>' is assignable to the constraint of type 'TModel', but 'TModel' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'object'.

Which is actually good, because this highlights the next (invalid) situation:

```js
hoc((m: { name: string }) => m.name, { name: '' })('STRING IS UNWANTED');
```

To avoid this, I rewritten the `hoc` to the next one (pay attention to the conditional operator):

```js
const hoc = <TModel extends object, TInject extends Partial<TModel>, TRes>(callback: (m: TModel) => TRes, inject: TInject) =>
    (m: TInject extends TModel? never : Omit<TModel, keyof TInject> ) =>
        callback({ ...m as unknown as TModel, ...inject })

hoc((m: { name: string }) => m.name, { name: '' })('STRING IS UNWANTED');
```

Now the code works as expected. However, I also have to add `...m as unknown as TModel` to make it compilable.

So, my question is **how to get the same functionality but without direct casting** which, actually breaks the TS idea.

**UPDATE:**

What problem I am trying to solve.

Imagine we have a function that can greet the user. To make it work we need the user name and how to greet him. The user is something dynamic, it comes from the backend. The greetings, however, is something static that is known at the compile time. So I want to have a factory that will combine this data into one:

```js
const greeter = (data) => `${data.greetings}, ${data.userName}`;
const factory = (func, static) => (data) => func({ ...data, ...static });

const greet = factory(greeter, { greetings: "hello" });
const greeting = greet({ userName: "Vitalii" });

console.log(greeting);
```

From TypeScript I want to check that types are compatible, and see what fields are required after such "currying" (it's not currying). **The solution should be generic.** Does this make sense?

Comment: Does it work for you https://tsplay.dev/NBeVbw ?

Comment: @captain-yossarian Seems no because of the error in this valid code: `hoc((m: { name: string, age: number }) => m.name, { name: '',  })({age: 4 });`

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66706012/infer-function-generic-type-u-from-return-value-of-passed-function) ?

Comment: Does intersection of `inject` and `m` should extend `TModel`?

Comment: The intersection of the TModel and TInject should exists. They must have at least one common field. Extending is not required.  I will try to update the question with the real use case, seems this is needed.

Comment: @Drag13 extend it, at least to have the code references, try to have something executable

Comment: Don't get the idea, sorry. The code and types are already working. The only issue is to get rid of `as` statement and find the correct "typescript way". @DavidLemon

Comment: The problem is that TypeScript is not clever enough to determine that one generic type is assignable to another while the types are not resolved. That's why the function call works, successfully errors out when passing incompatible types, and successfully computes the final return type. However, inside the implementation, the types do not resolve and TypeScript simply does not know that `TInject & Omit<TModel, keyof TInject>` with `TInject` constrained to `extends Partial<TModel>` is assignable to `TModel`. Although it's not very satisfying, you might have to write `{ ...inject, ...m} as any`

Comment: Somewhat related question about TypeScript not being able to correlate a constructor and it's parameters types in a factory: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70082173/typescript-factory-pattern-with-parameters/70082454#comment123891662_70082454. Problem solved with a good old `any` cast in the implementation

Comment: @GuerricP `any`, `as` is kinda cheating I would highly like to omit. However if it is not possible I will use them of course

Comment: @Drag13 I don't like it either but I strongly doubt you can solve this problem without a cast

Comment: @GuerricP with the help of community and some digging I finally did that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some extra efforts I've finally got expected result:

```
function factory<
    TCallback extends (arg: any) => any,
    TModel extends Parameters<TCallback>[0],
    TInjected extends Partial<TModel>
>(callback: TCallback, injected: TInjected) {
    return function <TProps extends Omit<TModel, keyof TInjected>>(props
        : TProps extends object
        ? TProps
        : never): ReturnType<TCallback> {
        return callback({ ...injected, ...props });
    }
}

const greeter = (_: { greeting: string; name: string }) => "";

// "Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'"
const x = factory(greeter, {
    greeting: "hello",
    name: "Vitalii",
})("Joker");

// Argument of type '{ xxxx: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Omit<UserGreetings, "greeting">'.
// Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'xxxx' does not exist in type 'Omit<UserGreetings, "greeting">'.
const x2 = factory(greeter, {
    greeting: "hello",
})({ xxxx: "test" });

// Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Omit<UserGreetings, "greeting">'.
// Property 'name' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Omit<UserGreetings, "greeting">'.
const x3 = factory(greeter, {
    greeting: "hello",
})({});

const x4 = factory(greeter, {
    greeting: "hello",
})({ name: 'test' });
```

[Link to working playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgQ2FEAnAnjAvDAPAWACgYSYBhBAG0oCMkBrGAUwA8omwATCGACgVQBzAFwwEYdAEpsAPhgA3EAEtOAGiKkYAQSHM2HbjAAKAhAFsm7VBFwVqdYPRkBtAAwBddcVIBpMCAB3MCNUEAAHHlZ2Lh4TVCglKlwdQRkvTRleYCpaBlE7XMdVGHp-IJDwiFE-QODQiOksGQ1SXAA5JgCKiL1owwB5MyUoZKFi%20iZ0EDgYGvL6iBlMsE7uqpgOroXegx4UmAB%20GBX5JlQYUU21nZiYEBoAKyZkQ43V7dETs8bm700SbL2Bi8ADeMAAdJDSrU1sVIeCVltKjAAL6SADcRCIUHQYSYMAAqhAzgBxVBMSxKMCCHg4MGCcmU6miaCoKmCYpgcxMFlQNnU4oIQRMA6fACuZhoZ1RWMIoEgsAZFKs2D4AH1RETSYyEtSID8YAByQ2ygD0pvgCCUlB4AWGAAtmKhQucAEQpCUcWDTGA4vFG1nsw0wJQ8fywBAQCBKQRcmiUfEoGBhUwWFU%20v34w1fVCG11ERDINDoXhKyxnYoglokMu6kQwV32pjUECu9KkLkWUSugBqwyoSiUbaIaN4roAUiAJqhXRizRbENbbQ6nS6Gx6LGBvTNM0aQSjg6HjiAI1GY3GE76QMnU%20XzhncVmc3mC0gUBhSzqKzAq38YLX2W7JsW2HP9Ox5Bs%20ygAchy8Ud9znQgiHNbQhE9Lc7h3R89xgFg8JYXl%20UEdFUUPMMTzEM9YwQeNE2vFNUG5dMsP9Q1BmGXAtVQMllXZCBildADqVdGRDXBZCLX6R5nlgShhjOKgYDMBBMHAShMAgPFgCUOBMGhIJk3qM4EiYfixC4I18JYYNOBAUzj1gVhQ1gKlfWwtihhGLieKZGkBKEwQRLE18iw-Wtv1-TQAqA5tKFbODJFBXD8NEQ12GgYM0UxJDCBQjcvUwtzWP3MiHMo6NqNoq8b0YtNpQfVj2K84luJ1Pj-La4TRPE3KLW6YzMGzblSqGM9qRDMAiqzEqYBoMVYHJABHMUlHJTgJqmo0ms4lqfLrMzBM6wLupC98S3C1BK2rf8jpikCEtBLL5xgFCAHU0HoZcoEdOAxWoGAAEkt1ipQAGUOGJGAIDFMIwjQKAAEIkdO4tP2VCLruihtgLi0D4OOblUvSqBMoxIA)

Big thanks to @DimaParzhitsky for the main idea

Answer (score 2):

Would that do the trick?

```
const factory = <
    Callback extends (arg: any) => void,
    Arg extends Parameters<Callback>[0],
    KnownProps extends Partial<Arg>,
>(callback: Callback, knownProps: KnownProps) =>
    <
        NewProps extends Omit<Arg, keyof KnownProps>,
    >(...[newProps]: NewProps extends {} ? [object?] : [NewProps]) =>
        callback({ ...knownProps, ...newProps });
```

*[Try it](https://tsplay.dev/WyOZdN).*

This is somewhat similar to what you have come up with, but the order of inference is just slightly different:

- constraint the first argument to be a function with one parameter;
- infer the type of the parameter;
- constraint the second argument to be an excerpt of the above type;
- constraint the inner function's argument to be a complimentary excerpt.

In case if `knownProps` includes *all* properties of the `Arg`, and no new properties are expected, to avoid overly inclusive typings, there is an explicit condition that makes the inner function's argument an optional generic object.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer, it looks really great.  Is it possible to omit this situation: 
```const greet = factory(greeter, { greetings: "hello", userName: 'asd' });
const greeting = greet('test');```

Comment: I've updated the answer, check it out

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky nice solution!